# Is there a name for being able to substitute a variable for the source code assigned to it?

Tags: python, terminology, language-agnostic, naming, matlab

Consider the following (python) code

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = 2 + 3
z = x[0] + y
```

Here, I can substitute the expressions for `x` and `y` verbatim in the expression for `z`, possibly by surrounding then in some grouping syntax:

```
y = [1, 2, 3, 4][0] + (2 + 3)
```

---

Not all languages have this feature. Consider the following equivalent Matlab code

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4];
y = 2 + 3
z = x(1) + y;
```

Here, no such transformation is possible, and both of the following would be a syntax error:

```
z = [1, 2, 3, 4](1) + (2 + 3);
z = ([1, 2, 3, 4])(1) + (2 + 3);
```

PHP behaves in a similar way.

---

**Does this property of a language have a name?** Is there a concise way to describe this property of a language? Specifically, being able to make source-code substitutions of expression subtrees

Comment: Yes, it's called **substitution.**  If you're looking for an adjective, **substitutability.**  Two functions or expressions may or may not be **compatible** with each other for reasons of **type compatibility.**   See http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs312/2008sp/lectures/lec05.html for more information on "The Substitution Model of Evaluation."

Comment: some IDEs call that *inline variable*

Comment: The distinction I'm trying to make here is substitution of value vs substitution of syntax.

Comment: What would you like to know about that?  Whether or not you can do some thing in a particular programming language depends on whether or not it is **supported,** which is a function of the **language specification.**

Comment: @RobertHarvey: My question is, given the sentence "Language Y supports X", does there exist a term "X"  that names this feature? Is there a specific word used to describe it in the context of programming language design?

Comment: What you're describing is simply **expression evaluation.**  `y = [1, 2, 3, 4][0] + 2` works because the expression `[1, 2, 3, 4][0] ` is *evaluated to a number* before that number is then added to 2.

Comment: I wasn't _trying_ to describe that! I guess I'm looking for "grammar substitution" or something

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with grammar.  It has to do with the language specifications.  Matlab apparently does not support the required expression evaluations to make this work.  It's not a "feature," as such, nor is it likely to have a name other than something like "incremental evaluation of nested or complex numeric expressions."  I think it's fair to say that this capability is generally expected in any programming language worth its salt; perhaps it's omitted from Matlab for performance reasons.

Comment: It's also entirely possible you're not doing it right in Matlab and it does have this capability.  I haven't written anything in Matlab myself, so I can't say for sure.

Comment: have you considered "referential transparency"?  It talks about substituting values, but might possibly apply to substituting expressions as symbolic values.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: MATLAB does not have this property. Array subscripting can only be performed on variables and certain expressions (such as cell subscripts and field references) but not general expressions. So even if you think MATLAB" not worth its salt, it is a widely used language and the question is perfectly legitimate

Comment: @AndreasH. It was not my intention to insult Matlab or its adherents.  As I pointed out myself, I haven't used it.  Matlab is arguably a domain-specific language, though.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: no offense taken. It certainly has to do with MATLABs language design. I would even say it contains some very deep flaws but still it is used. So there must be a name for the property the OP mentions which makes the question valid and in my opinion an interesting question. Perhaps not obvious to everyone who has not worked with a language which sometimes forces use of temporaries.

Comment: @AndreasH.  It's called *substitution,* or sometimes the "substitution model."  I mentioned that in my very first comment, with a supporting link which undoubtedly has gone unread.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: From that link, _"In the substitution model, the bound variable is replaced with the value that it is bound to"_. This happens in matlab too. The problem is, matlab does not possess the syntax/grammar to allow the programmer to make this substitution _in their source code_. This is not about evaluation, this is about syntax. I agree though, it's entirely possible that this feature does not have a name, because if the feature is taken for granted, then no-one would need to name it.

Comment: Perhaps a more familar example would be C: `int x[] = {1, 2, 3, 4}; int w = x[0];` is valid, but `int w = {1, 2, 3, 4}[0];` is not.

Comment: @Eric: Sounds like the name for that is *Compile-Time Expression Evaluation.*

Answer (score 1):

It's called "variables"! In a language with immutable variables (versus mutable/assignable variables), the semantics *by definition* says that we just replace a variable by the expression assigned to it wherever it occurs. This is generally a property of languages based on the lambda calculus (e.g. System F, Haskell, ML, Idris, etc).

The substitution operator is written `[M/x]N`: we replace any free occurrences of the variable `x` in `N` with `M`. For example, the dynamics of function application makes use of this operator: if we have a lambda abstraction `lambda x: int. x + x`, then

`(lambda x: int: t. x + x)(5)` -> `[5/x](x+x)` -> `5+5` -> `10`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is call *substitution*, or *inlining*.

Typically *inlining* is used to refer the process done by the compiler, in which expressions like `y` are evaluated, and their result substituted in place of the references to `y`.

It's not necessarily limited to variables, either. Functions can be inlined, which allows the body of the function to be substituted for the call to the function. This typically increases the application's size, but improves performances by removing the need for a function call to be performed.

Comment: "Inlining" is a compiler-specific term.  "Substitution" is a more general term that can be applied to more situations (including language syntax) than the very specific thing that a compiler does when it inlines.  So "substitution" is the better term here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I agree, but inlining is used colloquially here too. Actually, more than colloquially, because some IDEs refactorers call it that